# Error processing robots.txt

Tags: glass-mapper, dependency-injection

I occasionally see the below error in my logs

```
Error processing robots.txt
Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperExceptioMessage: Service has been disposed, cannot create object
```

My code in Robotservice is as below

```
        #region Injected
        //DI Implementation
        private readonly IMvcContext _mvcContext;

        public RobotsService(IMvcContext mvcContext)
        {
            _mvcContext = mvcContext; 
        }

        #endregion

        public string GetRobotsForItem()
        {
            var homeItem = _mvcContext.GetHomeItem<ISitecoreItem>();
            ...
            ...
           return <some text>;
        }
```

While debugging, I see that the `data source is null` for `_mvcContext` and hence Glass is complaining about this. When I searched(blogs, pages, etc) for this error, I see that DI should be implemented and is the solution for this error. But I already have DI Implemented and working in almost all scenarios. Any thoughts or ideas on this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to resolve your dependencies explicitly as shown below:

```
    public string GetRobotsForItem()
    {
        var mvcContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMvcContext >();
        var homeItem = mvcContext.GetHomeItem<ISitecoreItem>();
        ...
        ...
       return <some text>;
    }
```

Hope this helps

If you getting same issue, you need to share how you are invoking this service please?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I changed my code as specified but still get the same error.

Comment: I think you need to clean up your code and do away with the Interface variable. I will edit my suggested solution